# Inserting an existing root into an existing Python ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm trying to link two existing Python ElementTree objects together.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element('Hello')
root2 = ET.Element('World')
node = ET.SubElement(root2, 'country')
node.text = 'Belgium'
```

When printed

```
print(ET.tostring(root))
print(ET.tostring(root2))
```

I get

```
b'<Hello />'
b'<World><country>Belgium</country></World>'
```

How do I add root2 to root, to get the result? `

```
print(ET.tostring(root))

b'<Hello><World><country>Belgium</country></World></Hello>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that I can use the same syntax as in lists

```
root.append(root2)

print(ET.tostring(root))

b'<Hello><World><country>Belgium</country></World></Hello>'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

```
hello = ET.Element('Hello')
world = ET.Element('World')
hello.insert(0,world)
country = ET.SubElement(world,'Country')
country.text = 'Belgium'
print(ET.tostring(hello))
```

Output

```
b'<Hello><World><Country>Belgium</Country></World></Hello>'
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer the question. "root" and "root2" are pre-existing ElementTree Objects, so the question is how to link them or how to turn a root element into a sub element late. In my real world use case, these come from different sources...

Comment: Code was modified accordingly